# Check if class contains all array items?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I am trying to see if a divs classes contains all array items, and then add "display: block" to that div.

If I would like to add "display: block" to each individual class, I would do it like this:

```
let arrayList = [car, animal, boat]

for(i=0; i<arrayList.length; i++) {
    let getClass = document.getElementsByClassName(arrayList[i]);
    for(c=0; c<getClass.length; c++) {
        getClass[c].style.display ="block";
    }
}
```

But how can I check if all classes of a div is in the `arrayList`? And then add "display: block" to it?

For example, if I have one div with structure `<div class="car animal boat">` I would like it to have "display: block", but if the div structure is `<div class="car animal">` I would like it to have "display: none".

The array will be dynamic. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to use the [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)? If so, you could simply use the built in matching to get you the element/s you want by building a query string from your array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll`:

```js
let classes = ["car", "animal", "boat"]
, classTest = "." + classes.join(".")

document.querySelectorAll(classTest).forEach(div => div.style.display = "block")
```

```css
div { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="car animal boat">Show Me</div>
<div class="car boat">Hide</div>
<div class="car animal">Hide</div>
<div class="car animal boat">Show Me too</div>
```